# 502 bad gateway after redirecting to https django

Tags: django, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, digital-ocean

I've been trying to encrypt my website with https, but when redirecting I get 502 bad gateaway, I use Digital Ocean with nginx on Ubuntu 14 and django:
Here is my server config:

```
upstream app_server {
     server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
 }

server {
   # listen 80 default_server;
   # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name =  programmationetia.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/programmationetia.com/fullchain.pem ;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/programmationetia.com/privkey.pem;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
       alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass https://app_server;
    }

}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name programmationetia.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}
```

I followed Sentex tutorial on encrypting with ssl.
Thank you for helping

Comment: What is logged in your nginx error log and is there anything in the django logs (logs of Gunicorn, Uwsgi)? What are the values of your django.conf.settings for SECURE_SSL_* and SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER?

Comment: Is gunicorn running correctly? Often a 502 mean that nginx cannot connect to gunicorn

Comment: You are right Fran, the connection with gunicorn.socket failed because there is no such file or directory. Thank you a lot

Comment: The error log is 2019/02/03 13:31:03 [crit] 13977#13977: *1 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.3.249.164, server: =, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "programmationetia.com"

Comment: The values of SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER is ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https') and I don't find SECURE_SSL_*

Comment: Could you help me with generating a new gunicorn.socket file

Comment: Is gunicorn running (ps faux | grep gunicorn) and can you post your gunicorn config please?